# Dynamically generate nested inputs in form

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, vue.js

I'm very new into frontend, so I appreciate any help.
I'm trying to build a form, where user select an option from  element and then depending on condition, dynamically generates another one  (and some other inputs) as a child elements.

Finally what I'm trying to get is JSON with nested structure. E.g.

```
fields: [{type: 'List', value: [{type: 'Map', value: [{type: 'Integer', value: 5}, {type: 'List', value: [and so on...]]]}]
```

I have already started to code it in native JS and this is what I have so far (snippet below).

I want to release something similar with **VUE.js library** (or maybe someone can tell me any other useful libraries), cuz I want to control visibility of my inputs based on some conditions and some other useful features...but I dont know how to dynamically push elements into nested into nested and so on...I appriciate any help, any ideas and any examples. Thanks!

```js
 let template = `
             <select name="type" onChange="createChildElement(this)"  aria-label="Select type">
                 <option value="List">Select type</option>
                 <option value="List">List</option>
                 <option value="Map">Map</option>
                 <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
             </select>
             <select name="method" aria-label="Метод генерации">
                 <option value="Static">Static</option>
                 <option value="Random">Random</option>
                 <option value="Range">Range</option>
             </select>
             <input name="size" type="text" placeholder="Size">
             <input name="value" type="text" placeholder="Value">
         `;

function createChildElement(e) {
if(e.value == "List") {
    var x = document.createElement('ul');
    var z = document.createElement('li');
    z.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', template );
   x.appendChild(z);

   e.parentNode.appendChild(x);
   }
   if(e.value == "Map") {
    var x = document.createElement('ul');
    var z = document.createElement('li');
    z.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', template );
   x.appendChild(z);

       var y = document.createElement('ul');
    var n = document.createElement('li');
    n.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', template );
   y.appendChild(n);

   e.parentNode.appendChild(x);
   e.parentNode.appendChild(y);
   }
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main-container">
    <ul><li><div class="singleton-card ml-2">
        <select name="type" onChange="createChildElement(this)"  aria-label="Select type">
            <option value="List">Select type</option>
            <option value="List">List</option>
            <option value="Map">Map</option>
            <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
        </select>
        <select name="method" aria-label="Метод генерации">
            <option value="Static">Static</option>
            <option value="Random">Random</option>
            <option value="Range">Range</option>
        </select>
        <input name="size" type="text" placeholder="Size">
        <input name="value" type="text" placeholder="Value">
    </div></li></ul>
</div>
</body>
```

I just found this example (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vuejs/vuejs.org/tree/master/src/v2/examples/vue-20-tree-view?from-embed), I want to build something similar, but as a form with selects and inputs (just like my snippet example).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to create dependent dropdowns. You can check the following codepen for creating a dependent dropdown in vue.js

https://codepen.io/adnanshussain/pen/KqVxXL

JS

```
var model_options = {
  1: [{ text: "Accord", id: 1 }, { text: "Civic", id: 2 }],
  2: [{ text: "Corolla", id: 3 }, { text: "Hi Ace", id: 4 }],
  3: [{ text: "Altima", id: 5 }, { text: "Zuke", id: 6 }],
  4: [{ text: "Alto", id: 7 }, { text: "Swift", id: 8 }]
};

var makes_options = [
  { text: "Honda", id: 1 },
  { text: "Toyota", id: 2 },
  { text: "Nissan", id: 3 },
  { text: "Suzuki", id: 4 }
];

var vm_makes = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    make: null,
    model: null,
    makes_options: makes_options,
    model_options: model_options,
  },
  watch: {
    make: function(event) {
      $('#vehicle-models').dropdown('clear');
    }
  }
});

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
```

HTML

```
<div id="app" class="ui grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui label">Vechicle Make</div>
      <select class="ui dropdown" v-model="make" id="vehicle-makes">
        <option v-for="option in makes_options" v-bind:value="option.id">
          {{ option.text }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="ui label">Vechicle Model</div>
      <select class="ui dropdown" id="vehicle-models" v-model="model">
        <option 
          v-for="option in model_options[make]" 
          :value="option.id" 
          :key="option.id"
        >
          {{ option.text }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah, that's not what I'm trying to do :( I want to generate child (nested) element based on select condition from user. And then in that generated element, user can again select option that will produce a new child (nested) element inside that first generated element. And so on...